# My passport containing Schengen visa completely washed prior to start of my trip to a Schengen state, now what do I have to do to get new visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, afghan-citizens

I'm Afghan citizen and still in my country (Afghanistan), I received Schengen visa from Swiss embassy in Pakistan and now my passport containing Schengen visa is completely washed prior to start of my trip to Swiss for a training, now I got my second passport from my country and what to know whether I can get a new Schengen visa or not? and what do I have to do to get new visa? What documents do I have to have? And how long re-issuing Schengen visa will take?

Comment: Did you try contacting the relevant consulate?

Comment: It is weekend and the the relevant consulate is off. in other hand, I have very short time to start my trip.

Comment: You will have to get your Schengen visa reissued. You will need to go through the whole visa application process again. This is the rule for several countries I have experience with, so I assume it is the same with Schengen visa.

Comment: Can you show that embassy your damaged passport, and that you have it canceled by the issuing authority? Then they may stamp another visa on your new passport. In my opinion, you must show them that your previous passport cannot be used at all in future.

Comment: BTW, I cannot understand "visa is completely washed". Do you mean literally in a washing machine? Does it happen a lot, with other important stuff too?

Answer (score 2):

To re-issue the existing visa, you need to make an appointment directly at the embassy. Call them at  +92518485836 and request for an appointment and explain the situation.

They will be the best to guide you further.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=AF&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CH&selDest=Switzerland&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Valid visas in full, invalidated travel documents are
>     accepted provided accompanied by a new travel document.

So if the visa is still in acceptable condition (legible with the machine code intact), you just need to bring both passports. At the Swiss border, present the old passport open at the visa page, and the new one open at the main ID page.

If the visa is damaged as well, you need to get it re-issued. Contact the Swiss embassy regarding this

Answer (score -4):

Now you must apply new visa application with all same documents and photocopies attached With old passport. And also submit a cover letter to explain what happened with the old passport and apologize for reapply the visa.

Comment: I doubt this is right. Normally you would have to report the loss of your passport (with information as precise as possible) and re-obtain the old visa.